# Why aren't hard links considered a file like any other?

Tags: linux, hyperlink

I have a program (in this case it's omxplayer) that plays mp4 files just fine. But when I ask it to play a file that is actually a hard link, it refused.

OriginalFile.mp4 = plays fine

cp OriginalFile.mp4 /folder/OriginalFile.mp4 = plays fine

cp -al OriginalFile.mp4 /folder/OriginalFile.mp4 = refused to play the hard link

Omxplayer just gives me the errors: thread nextreader 0x36af00 (0) thread opened 0x36af00 (0) openok 0

My question is not only specific for omxplayer. In general I'm wondering how a program can determine if it's a hard link or an original file, isn't it actually the same thing from a programs point of view?!

Comment: odd behaviour...  It's trivial to tell if a file has hard links (call `stat` and look for `st.st_nlink > 1` but I can't imagine why the media player should care.  NB: semantically there should be no difference between the original file and the hard-linked "copy" - they both point to the same file inode.

Comment: A hardlink *is* actually the same as the original file from any context. Your problem is not related to hardlinks, even if it might look like for you.

Comment: I just created a hardlink and played some music. It worked fine. Are the two files (links) in the same partition?

Comment: @NikhilBaliga hard links _must_ by definition be in the same partition - creating a cross-partition hard link should fail.

Comment: Yeah they should be in same partition... That I knew. I didn't know they couldn't be created at all (logical though, mea culpa)

Comment: @hek2mgl That's the way I understood it too, yet I kept getting the error messages (and the size of the hard links was 1 byte I think). Now its working, and I have no idea what I did differently now. :-/

Comment: I don't have an idea too.. However, even the kernel cannot *detect* a hard link. It is just another name for the same thing (file).

Comment: what file system are you creating those hardlinks on? Can you, after creating a hardlink, still play from the original file name?

Comment: @Bushmills It seemed so, but now I can't recreate the problem… So I guess I must have done something else wrong.